# Why is it that when I copy the video using the VideoWriter of opencv, the data becomes very large, 6 times as large as the original video

Tags: python, opencv

```
video = "myVideo.mp4"
out_vidoe_path = "cooy_myVideo.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)    
video_FourCC = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
video_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
video_size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
              int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
vwriter = cv2.VideoWriter(out_vidoe_path, video_FourCC,video_fps, video_size, isColor=True)

flag = True
while flag:
    flag, dis = cap.read()
    newDis = dis
    vwriter.write(newDis)

cap.release()
vwriter.release()
```

> This code is just to copy the original video, I did not expect to copy
>   after a lot of bigger, is I where not to do good

Answer (score 0):

It is because the compression rate of the video created by VideoWriter is different from that of your original video. You can choose a different method by changing FourCC but unfortunately you have no control over the compression rate.

What I do is that I create the video by OpenCV, then compress it using FFMPEG by the following command in Linux: 
`ffmpeg -i uncompressed.avi -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 compressed.mkv`
You can change the compression rate, which is `0` here (lossless).